# javascript object appears null but object.property returns data

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to set a object var but for some reason this object will not allow me to set a variable, but it still shows up.

```
Theme.opts.series = series_data.series;     
console.log(Theme.opts);
console.log(Theme.opts.series);
```

In the above example the first console log returns an object but series is null.
The second console log returns the contents of series_data.series as expected.

Why would it appear to be null when the other says that it is there?

Let me know if you need more info. Series holds arrays that are 1000+.

**I can also set this to any other property except series. So Theme.opts.foo = series_data.series works as expected.**

Comment: Could you provide more info ? what browser are you using with console.log? how is Theme.opts initialized? did you initialize Theme.opts.series before the assignment ? -- providing actual outputs would be very helpful ...

Comment: @Smokie - http://pastebin.com/bxp6SWr0 (before) -http://pastebin.com/3d8qfHvR (the object after setting the series_data.series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `Theme.opts` first:

```
Theme.opts = {};
Theme.opts.series = series_data.series;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but Theme.opts is already an object. Otherwise I would get the error "cannot add "whatever" to undefined index opts... or something like that.

Comment: How is `Theme.opts` being defined? That might help to clarify your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LaKdv/ is working as expected in Chrome, so I suspect there might be something going on in the rest of your code that is messing with things.

Comment: Why would it display the proper data only when console is logging the exact object? The rest of the code has no time to do anything. If Theme.opts.series pulls back data, shouldn't Theme.opts show data for the series object?

Comment: ended up being something completely unrelated.